# How can I prevent the hash symbol from showing in Excel when cells are too small?

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting

Every so often I'm bugged by the fact that Excel replaces the contents of cells with '######' for certain number formats when the cell is too small.

It hasn't been a major problem up until now, when it messes with the output of my macros which relies upon the displayed text i.e. the currency symbol; which does not form part of the data in the cell.

Is there a way to turn this feature off and have the numbers clipped or overflow as it does with text?

This is specifically for cases where I want my cells to have a certain size or I want to hide my cells that this needs to be addressed. I've tried extensive Googling, but didn't find a solution, nor even similar questions yet.

A temporary workaround I have for this is to enable the shrink-to-fit for the cell alignment but I would ideally just like to turn it off.

I understand that this feature is to prevent misreading numbers that are cut off, but this doesn't bother me for my purposes right now.

Comment: Shrink to fit seems to be your only option if column widths have to be fixed.

Comment: You can try to change the cell format to General.

Comment: @IbrahimHassan That won't work, as then I don't have the currency symbol in the text, which is what I need for my macros to work

Comment: then it's the fault of your macro. The `###...` doesn't affect the underlying value. All references to that cell will correctly use the true value regardless of how the value is being display

Answer (score 0):

Autofit the column width before you refer to the cell text.

e.g.

```
With ActiveCell
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Debug.Print .Text
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the cells/columns/what-have-you as TEXT before entering the data (or after with some effort to deal with some effects Excel might have already done, like showing one in scientific notation.)

That way you get the "clipping" effect and no changing your apparent formatting to scientific notation or to the hash marks.

In MOST cases of using those numbers in later calculations, Excel will happily interpret them as numbers even though the formatting is as TEXT. So adding them to something, etc., will work nicely.

Functions like `SUM()` will not though. For them, wrapping a range or cell reference in the `VALUE()` function will solve that:  `SUM(VALUE(A1:B5))` nicely sums all such  data in the range.

However, any function (or menu command, etc.) that can logically be expected to find text vs. number an important difference will fail without extra steps. Lookup functions for instance. Or using the Ribbon menu's Filtering functionality will see anything formatted as text as different from things formatted as numbers or general.

So, `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(VALUE(A1),B1:E4,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A1,B1:E4,2,FALSE))` might solve the problem, though one may need something more involved if the lookup is more complicated

Lastly, all bets are off when using the data in Pivot Tables, in Power Pivot, or in Power Query. (PQ being the least iffy of them.)

But just need basic, palliative care here? Do the formatting as text and see if it solves things without immediate follow-on difficulties.